# Смена изображений через определенный интервал времени по кругу

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtimer

Мне нужно сделать программу, которая помимо смены картинки по кнопке, будет также менять их с каким-то временным промежутком по кругу.

Картинки меняются по кругу с помощью двух переменных. 
Пытался сделать это через `while` и модуль **time**, но тогда цикл `while` будет выполняться бесконечно, и программа даже не открывается.

```
import time

i = 2
n = 3

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1920, 1080)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.photo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.photo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-4, -18, 1920, 540))
        self.photo.setText("")
        self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("NPHsMHXrqxw.png"))
        self.photo.setScaledContents(True)
        self.photo.setObjectName("photo")
        self.left = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.left.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 210, 71, 41))
        self.left.setObjectName("left")
        self.left.setText("Left")
        self.right = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.right.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1850, 230, 71, 41))
        self.left.setObjectName("right")
        self.right.setText("Right")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1920, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.right.clicked.connect(self.show_next)
        self.left.clicked.connect(self.show_previous)

        
        

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.left.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Left"))
        self.right.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Right"))

    def show_next(self):
        global i
        global n
        if i == 2:
            self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("71gEpF2OMb8.png"))
            i = 3
            n = 1
        elif i == 3:
            self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("loXBtxufzps.png"))
            i = 1
            n = 2
        elif i == 1:
            self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("NPHsMHXrqxw.png"))
            i = 2
            n = 3


    def show_previous(self):
        global i
        global n
        if n == 3:
            self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("loXBtxufzps.png"))
            n = 2
            i = 1
        elif n == 2:
            self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("71gEpF2OMb8.png"))
            i = 3
            n = 1
        elif n == 1:
            self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("NPHsMHXrqxw.png"))
            n = 3
            i = 2



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать циклы не получится, поскольку оконный цикл событий никогда не продолжится. Вам надо использовать асинхронные варианты. Самое простое - использование таймера `QTimer`. Добавьте в ваш setupUi:

```
    self.timer = QtCore.QTimer() # создание таймера
    self.timer.setInterval(1000) # установите интервал срабатывания в миллисекундах
    self.timer.setSingleShot(False) # Скажите таймеру что срабатывать надо не один раз, а повторять бесконечно
    self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.show_next()) # При срабатывании таймера вызовем функцию перехода к следующей картинке
    self.timer.start() # теперь можно таймер запустить. Он будет бесконечно крутиться пока работает программа
```

Answer (score 1):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ** код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, **НИКОГДА**. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

[**Почему глобальные переменные - зло?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

```
#import time
#i = 2
#n = 3
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1220, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.photo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.photo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-4, -18, 1220, 540))
        self.photo.setText("")
        self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("NPHsMHXrqxw.png"))
        self.photo.setScaledContents(True)
        self.photo.setObjectName("photo")
        self.left = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.left.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 210, 71, 41))
        self.left.setObjectName("left")
        self.left.setText("Left")
        self.right = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.right.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1150, 230, 71, 41))
        self.left.setObjectName("right")
        self.right.setText("Right")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1920, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

#        self.right.clicked.connect(self.show_next)
#        self.left.clicked.connect(self.show_previous)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.left.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Left"))
        self.right.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Right"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.i = 1         # 2
        
        self.right.clicked.connect(lambda: self.show_next(1))
#        self.left.clicked.connect(self.show_previous)
        self.left.clicked.connect(lambda: self.show_next(-1))
        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()      
        self.timer.setInterval(1000) 
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.show_next(1)) 
        self.timer.start()


    def show_next(self, value):
#        global i
#        global n

        self.i += value
        if self.i > 3:
            self.i = 1
        elif self.i < 1:
            self.i = 3
            
        if self.i == 2:
            self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("lena-2.png"))
#            i = 3
#            n = 1
        elif self.i == 3:
            self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("im.png"))
#            i = 1
#            n = 2
        elif self.i == 1:
            self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png"))
#            i = 2
#            n = 3


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему не стоит изменять код сгенерированный QT designer? работаю в команде, на мой взгляд, так будет легче взаимодействовать с моим куском кода, если он будет в пределах одного класса

Comment: @cor3,  нет, прежде всего, файлы, сгенерированные pyuic, никогда не должны редактироваться. 
Эти файлы предназначены для использования исключительно в качестве импорта и 
всегда должны оставаться неизменными (подробнее об этом очень важном аспекте 
читайте в официальных рекомендациях по использованию Designer
    https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html